# Share application URL issue

Tags: facebook, url, share

When I post my applications url in my status (copying and pasting the url), the preview that I see is correct.. I can see the thumbnail that facebook extracted from my og:image tag along with the title and description...But... as soon as I press the post button, the title, image and description disappear and I am left with only the links to the page.
The url I am sharing contains **NOTHING** but the [open graph protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) meta tags...
Strangely.. this behavior does not occur when posting the URL as a comment - when posting as a comment all the og:tags are read correctly and displayed in my comment including image, title and description...

When using facebook's [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (formerly known as Linter), my url returns the correct mega og tag values... thumbnail, description, title are all correct.  The problem arises only after the post is made and appears in my news feed.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "The url I am sharing contains NOTHING but the open graph protocol meta tags" ?
How is that a link to your app then?

I think you might be doing the same mistakes I once did.

First of all, make sure you do not share the link to a page tab app. It won't work unless it's a link to a canvas app. If you want it as a link to a page tab app, use the trick here: http://nonsmokingarea.com/stream/items/view/4427/facebook-how-to-build-a-like-button-linking-to-a-particular-tab-on-a-page

Second, FB will extract the tags from the url in the og tag. So if you're using it thinking that FB will post using the og tags in your link and the url in the tag, you are wrong. FB will go to the url in the og tag and extract the data from there.

Can you give us the link that you want to share?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmixflakes.inmanage.info%2Fshare everything looks ok here. However, the post doesn't work, just like you said. It does work when the link is liked, when the og tags are correctly posted. I think this is a Facebook issue and it will be fixed after some time so give it a least a day or two